# Как правильно работать с инициализацией класса внутри другого класса в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Столкнулся со следующей ситуацией:

```
import random

class TextWrapper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION = random.randint(0, 100)


class Text():
    TextWrapper = TextWrapper()

    def __init__(self):
        self.DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION = random.randint(0, 100)

for i in range(3):
    t = Text()
    print('Text(DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION):', t.DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION)
    print('TextWrapper(STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION):', t.TextWrapper.STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION)
```

Вывод:

```
Text(DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION): 63
TextWrapper(STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION): 51
Text(DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION): 86
TextWrapper(STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION): 51
Text(DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION): 61
TextWrapper(STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION): 51
```

Естественно я ожидал, что `STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION` будет генерироваться каждый раз заново (как `DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION`). А на выходе получаю одно и тоже число (51).

Как мне решить эту проблему? Пробовал использовать `del`, описывать в классах деструктор. Но пока что не силен в таких вопросах.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код внутри определения класса (но вне его методов) выполняется только один раз - при запуске модуля. В первоначальном варианте ваш код создает поле класса (не объекта), которое будет иметь общее значение для всех экземпляров класса `Text`.

Чтобы получать новый экземпляр `TextWrapper` для каждого нового экземпляра `Text`, просто создавайте новый экземпляр при инициализации класса `Text` (т.е. в методе `__init__`):

```
import random

class TextWrapper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION = random.randint(0, 100)


class Text():
    def __init__(self):
        self.DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION = random.randint(0, 100)
        self.TextWrapper = TextWrapper()


for i in range(3):
    t = Text()
    print('Text(DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION):', t.DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION)
    print('TextWrapper(STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION):', t.TextWrapper.STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION)
```

Результат выполнения (пример):

```
Text(DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION): 84
TextWrapper(STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION): 15
Text(DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION): 62
TextWrapper(STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION): 12
Text(DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION): 63
TextWrapper(STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION): 95
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, гениально! Теперь я понял ошибку, и принцип!

Answer (score 2):

Унаследуйте `Text` от `TextWrapper`:

```
import random

class TextWrapper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION = random.randint(0, 100)


class Text(TextWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()   # вызов конструктора родительского класса
        self.DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION = random.randint(0, 100)

for i in range(3):
    t = Text()
    print('Text(DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION):', t.DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION)
    print('TextWrapper(STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION):', t.STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION)
```

Вывод:

```
Text(DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION): 92
TextWrapper(STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION): 62
Text(DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION): 14
TextWrapper(STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION): 53
Text(DATA_BLOCK_CONDITION): 11
TextWrapper(STANDARD_BLOCK_CONDITION): 44
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за предложенный вариант, приму к сведению. Но решение предложенное выше больше подходит, как ответ.